# how to hide local sign In view as part of a userjourney

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

we are using Custom SignUpSignIn(combined signup sign-in) policies. we have to create a user journey where the user is presented with only registration options, social IDP's and SignUp Now link. We have to hide local account sign-in option for this user journey.

How can I achieve this only for this user journey?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new "api.signup" content definition from the existing "api.signupsignin" content definition:

```
  <ContentDefinition Id="api.signup">
    <LoadUri>https://contoso.com/templates/signup.html</LoadUri>
    <RecoveryUri>https://contoso.com/templates/error.html</RecoveryUri>
    <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:unifiedssp:1.1.0</DataUri>
    <Metadata>
      <Item Key="DisplayName">Account Registration</Item>
    </Metadata>
  </ContentDefinition>
```

The `<LoadUri />` element for this "api.signup" content definition should reference a HTML file that hides the local account sign-in section using the following style:

```
#api > div.localAccount > div.entry {
  display: none;
}
```

You can then reference the "api.signup" content definition from the "CombinedSignInAndSignUp" orchestration step:

```xml
<OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signup">
  ...
</OrchestrationStep>
```